Are these delicata ok or picked too soon?
Did I pick these delicata squash too soon?  If so, can I ripen them indoors at all?  They looked so good in the garden but now I'm second-guessing myself.


Since they look good, why do you think they're unripe? Did you open and roast one? They're more bland than butternut or acorn.
